# Change plot size in R studio

Tags: r

```
plot.default(x=index(first_data_rds),
         y=CumReturns,
         type = "l",
         xlab="Date",
         ylab = "Returns",
         main="Comparing Returns for Selected Stocks")
```

second_data_rds <- all_data_rds[[2]]
CumReturns2 =as.double(cumsum(na.zero(second_data_rds$AReturn.Close)))

lines(x=index(second_data_rds),y=CumReturns2,col="blue")

third_data_rds <- all_data_rds[[3]]
CumReturns3 =as.double(cumsum(na.zero(third_data_rds$AReturn.Close)))

lines(x=index(third_data_rds),y=CumReturns3,col="red")

legend("bottomleft", legend=c(xtsAttributes(first_data_rds)$RIC,
xtsAttributes(second_data_rds)$RIC,
xtsAttributes(third_data_rds)$RIC),
col=c("black", "blue", 'red'), lty=1:3, cex=0.8)

I am creating a plot combining the adjusted returns of 03 stock symbols (02 symbols with returns ranging from 0 to -0.5, and one symbol with returns ranging from 0 to -0.8). However, my plot only displays within the range of 0 to -0.5, causing the symbol with returns in the range of 0 to -0.8 to be missing from the plot in a certain period of time. When I plot each symbol individually, there is no issue. How can I fix this?"

Comment: Add `ylim = c(-1, 1)` to your initial plot call. Adjust the numbers to whatever works best for you.